Getting Index out of range error while trying to scrape product code from a website (Using Python & Selenium)
Issue Description:
I am trying to automate a process where I can visit a website and scrape product details of top 100 products on that page and put it in an excel file.
Code Explanation:
I have a class Webscraper inside which I am calling two functions. First I am calling scroll_and_click_view_more function which is simply scrolling down the webpage that I am visiting. Then I am calling prod_vitals function which is extracting product code and product names from that webpage.
Error Description:
Whenever I am running below code upto a certain maximum no. of products, the code gets stuck after a point and throws Index out of range error. If I set max_count_of_products=50, code got stuck at line, If I set
max_count_of_products=100, code got stuck at 93. There is no fixed index where I am getting stuck, if I change the value of max_count_of_products, the point at which the code gets stuck is also changing.
I am attaching screenshots of the error below.
max_count_of_products=50

max_count_of_products=100

Please find my code below:
products_summary = []
max_count_of_products=100

def scroll_and_click_view_more(driver,href):
    flag=False
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight")               
    while True:
        try:                                                                   
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 800);")
            time.sleep(4)
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight")
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.product-tile')))
            except Exception as e:
                if new_height == last_height and flag==False:
                    print("Reached the end of the page and no product tiles were found: ",href)
                    return "No product tiles found" 
                else:
                    last_height = new_height
                    continue                                                                      
            div_count = 0
            flag=True                                                                                                                            
            response = driver.page_source                                             
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')                                
            div_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'product-tile')                              
            div_count = len(div_elements)                                                 
            if(div_count > max_count_of_products):                                                       
                return(driver.page_source)
            else:
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 300);")
                time.sleep(3) 
                new_height = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight")
                #print(new_height)
                if new_height == last_height:
                    return(driver.page_source)
                else:
                    last_height = new_height
        except Exception as e:                                                               
            print(e)
            break

def prod_vitals(soup,title,url):                                                                                                                                  
    count_of_items=1
    products_data = []                                                        # Array to store all product data for our excel sheet
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'product-tile'):                            # Iterate over each individual product-tile div tag
        if count_of_items<=max_count_of_products:                                                              
            count_of_items = count_of_items+1;                                                                                                             
            pro_code = div.select('div.css-1fg6eq7 img')[0]['id']
            pro_name = div.select('div.product-name a.css-avqw6d p.css-1d5mpur')[0].get_text()
            products_data.append({'Product Code': pro_code, 'Product Name': pro_name})      # Append the extracted data to the list     
            print("Count: ", count_of_items)
            print("Product Code: ",pro_code)
            print("Product Name: ",pro_name)
            print("\n")
        else:
            break
    time.sleep(5)

class WebScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://staging1-japan.coach.com/shop/new/women/?auto=true"
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(r"c:\Users\DELL\Documents\Self_Project\chromedriver.exe"), options=options)

    def scrape(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        time.sleep(5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'html.parser')            # Refresh the page source and parse it
        response = scroll_and_click_view_more(self.driver, 'Link')
        time.sleep(3)
        if response != "No product tiles found" and response != "Reached the end of the page.":
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
            prod_vitals(soup,'TITLE', self.url)
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0);")
            time.sleep(3)
            self.driver.close()
scraper = WebScraper()
scraper.scrape()                       
time.sleep(5)                         
scraper.driver.quit()

> Attaching the product div structure below:
<div class="css-0">
   <div class="css-1fg6eq7">
      <div tabindex="-1" style="padding-top: 125%;"></div>
         <img width="237.01" height="296" class="chakra-image css-14ql1gk" src="https://coach.scene7.com/is/image/Coach/cn731_b4ous_a0?$desktopProductTile$" fetchpriority="high" id="CN731 B4OUS" name="タビー 12" data-qa="cm_tile_link_pt_img" contain="none" alt="COACH®,タビー 12,ボディバッグ&amp;斜めがけバッグ,ﾄｩﾙｰ ﾋﾟﾝｸ">
   </div>
</div>

**Please find my code below with API method:**


def prod_vitals(title,url):                                                                                                                                  
count_of_items=1
products_data = []                                                        # Array to store all product data for our excel sheet
page = 0
list_price = 0                                                                   # Variable to store list price
sale_price = 0                                                                   # Variable to store sale price
discount1 = 0                                                                    # Variable to store discount% that is displayed on the site
discount2 = 0                                                                  # Variable to store discount% calculated manually
res = "Incorrect"
if '/shop' not in url:
    print("Not in url",url)
    return "No product tiles found"
try:
    while True: 
        page = page + 1 #page result start from 2 and each page contains 16 result
        ct = count_of_items + 15    #count to adjust loop as each page contains 16 results
        if(page==1):
            full_url = f"{url}"
        else:
            full_url = f"{url}?page={page}"
        if 'api/get-shop' not in full_url:
            full_url = full_url.replace('/shop', '/api/get-shop')
        session = requests.Session()
        response = session.get(full_url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        products = response.json().get('pageData', {}).get('products', [])
        #products = len(response.json()['pageData']['products'])
        print(full_url,"\n", len(products),"\n")
        if '/get-shop' in full_url and not products:
            print("No product tiles found",full_url)
            return "No product tiles found"
        #print(response.json()['pageData']['products'],"\n")
        for i in products:
            print(i['defaultVariant']['prices'],"\n")
            pro_code = i['defaultColor']['vgId']
            #print(pro_code)
            pro_name = i['name']
            #print(pro_name)
            pdpurl = i['defaultColor']['url']
            #print(pdpurl,"\n")
            sale_price = i['defaultVariant']['prices']['currentPrice'] if i['defaultVariant']['prices']['currentPrice'] else 0
            list_price = i['defaultVariant']['prices']['regularPrice'] if 'regularPrice' in i['defaultVariant']['prices'] and i['defaultVariant']['prices']['regularPrice'] else 0
            discount1 = i['defaultVariant']['prices']['discount'] if i['defaultVariant']['prices']['discount'] and i['defaultVariant']['prices']['discount'] is not None else 0  
            if list_price > 0 and sale_price > 0:
                discount2 = round(((list_price - sale_price) / list_price) * 100)
                res = "Correct" if discount1 == discount2 else "Incorrect"
            elif(list_price ==0 and discount1 == 0):
                discount2 = 0
                res = "Correct"
            translator = Translator()
            translated_pro_name = translator.translate(pro_name, dest='en').text
            if count_of_items <= max_count_of_products: # condition to check if the count reach 100 or not, if count is less than 100 print, else stop printing
                #print(f'Product Count: {count_of_items}\nProduct Code: {pro_code}\nProduct Name: {translated_pro_name}\nProduct URL: {url+pdpurl}\nSale Price: {sale_price}\nList Price: {list_price}\nDiscount1: {discount1}\nDiscount2: {discount2}\nResult: {res}\n\n')
                products_data.append({'Product Code': pro_code, 'Product Name': translated_pro_name,'Product URL': url+pdpurl, 'Sale Price': '¥'+format(sale_price, '.2f'), 'List Price': '¥'+format(list_price, '.2f'), 'Discount on site': str(discount1)+'%', 'Actual Discount': str(discount2)+'%', 'Result': res})
                count_of_items = count_of_items + 1
                #continue
            else:
                break
        if ct > max_count_of_products: #if ct > count thats mean we reach our goal so break the loop
            break
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass




this was an exception made by your Python script because it didn't find the id value for some products (maybe a different variant of product ID/code was shown that didn't belong to div.css-1fg6eq7 well this will fix if you add exception handler, here is the modified version of code in prod_vitals function:
def prod_vitals(soup,title,url):                                                                                                                                  
    count_of_items=0
    products_data = []
    try:  #added error handler to avoid any disruption while the function is running                                                      # Array to store all product data for our excel sheet
        for div in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'product-tile'):                            # Iterate over each individual product-tile div tag
            if count_of_items<=max_count_of_products:
                #print(title)
                list_price = 0                                                                   # Variable to store list price
                sale_price = 0                                                                   # Variable to store sale price
                discount1 = 0                                                                    # Variable to store discount% that is displayed on the site
                discount2 = 0
                count_of_items = count_of_items+1;                                                                    # Variable to store discount% calculated manually
                res = "Incorrect"                                                                # Variable to store result of discount1==discount2; initialized with Incorrect
                pro_code = div.select('div.css-1fg6eq7 img')[0]['id']
                pro_name = div.select('div.product-name a.css-avqw6d p.css-1d5mpur')[0].get_text()
                products_data.append({'Product Code': pro_code, 'Product Name': pro_name})      # Append the extracted data to the list     
                print("Count: ", count_of_items)
                print("Product Code: ",pro_code)
                print("Product Name: ",pro_name)
                print("\n")
            else:
                break
    except Exception:
        pass
    time.sleep(3)

Second method:
All of the info that you're targeting is fetched from this API endpoint https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/get-shop/new/women?page=2 with JSON response, so we can gather this information faster than selenium, with a couple of lines of code using requests module.
Here is the code:
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning) #disable urllib warning

count = 0
headers = {
    "Cookie":"auth-bypass=true;" #this cookie value is mandatory for this apps otherwise its throwing '401 Unauthorized' error
}
page = 1
while True: 
    page = page + 1 #page result start from 2 and each page contains 16 result
    ct = count + 15 #count to adjust loop as each page contains 16 results
    url = f"https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/get-shop/new/women?page={page}"
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    for i in response.json()['pageData']['products']:
        code = i['productId']
        name = i['name']
        count = count + 1
        if count < 101: # condition to check if the count reach 100 or not, if count is less than 100 print, else stop printing
            print(f'Product Count: {count}\nProduct Code: {code}\nProduct Name: {name}\n\n')
        
    if ct > 100: #if ct > count thats mean we reach our goal so break the loop
        break
    


Putting in try catch block doesn't solve the issue though. Issue is not because it can't find the ID. ID is there. If I change the max_count, the no. of products for which I can see the product code is also changing. I feel issue is with infinity page loading. The product code value is inside the product image div, and I feel because of infinite scrolling, if image is not yet visible then it is not able to extract the div. I am not sure how to fix this issue and hence need help with. I am attaching the product div structure above in the question for clarity.

Also, if your second option can help fix this issue can you please explain a bit more how to modify above code with the requests module.

yeah, your guess is right this occurs due to the late loading of product images, it's worked on my end that's why I added the code in the answer, Also I included the second method code with the comment on it to explain. if you found this helpful then any support would be appreciated.

thanks a lot for your help. The fetching data through API made my code a lot faster. However, I am facing another issue now where with each run I am getting 'NoneType' object is not iterable error at random rows. There is no fixed place at which I am getting it. Please find my code above updated in the question.

hey, it is working fine on my end, maybe it's a connection error as I saw they're using Edgecast as their CDN, also stop printing exception error if you want clear output, thanks

Thank you @x1337loser worked for me as well later on.
